# Alternatives for MSHTA?

Tags: web-apps

On Windows systems, MSHTA.EXE is a "cheat" that allows you to create a file (.HTA extension) that uses a (large) subset of HTML plus jscript and/or VBScript to create simple applications that run locally. However, MSHTA uses the IE engine for rendering, with all the errors and vulnerabilities thus implied.

Other than setting up a web server, is there some way to get functionality essentially equivalent to HTAs, but using either gecko or webkit/chromium rendering? I am primarily interested in Windows 10 and later as the target platform, but would be quite pleased if a solution were to be cross-platform.

Comment: Are you aware of [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)?

Comment: @BrenBarn - That looks interesting, and may be my answer, although I was hoping for something that was basically "install-and-go", without needing to learn additional technologies (like node.js).